# Graph coloring - Q# -

Tags: programming, q#

I am checking Q# - Graph coloring

```
                for (C in 0 .. (1 <<< N) - 1) {
                InitializeColor(C, register);
```

Can you help me explain this part of the code?

Thnx

```
        for (N in 1 .. 4) {
            using (register = Qubit[N]) {
                for (C in 0 .. (1 <<< N) - 1) {
                    InitializeColor(C, register);
                    let measurementResults = MultiM(register);
                    Fact(ResultArrayAsInt(measurementResults) == C, 
                        $"Unexpected initialization result for N = {N}, C = {C} : {measurementResults}");
                    ResetAll(register);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: We'll need the definition of the Initialize Color method - can you share the link to the Github repo?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumKatas/blob/master/GraphColoring/Tests.qs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part of the **Graph Coloring Kata**. The `InitializeColor` is an operation that you must implement. The code above is part of the checker code to confirm the working of the implementation.

The code is used to check if the `InitializeColor` operation is implemented correctly. It is supposed to take an input `C` denoting the color as an non-negative integer. It is supposed to apply a unitary to convert the state $|000...0\rangle$ to state denoted by LittleEndian encoding of $|C\rangle$.

The `InitializeColor` operation is supposed to take a register which is in the state $|0..0\rangle$ and applies a Unitary which transforms it into a register in the state $|C\rangle$. The nextline measures the register using the `MultiM` operation.
The `Fact` function essentially confirms if the measured result in the state $|C\rangle$ and if not it print the error statement. The last line resets the register and brings it back to the state $|000..0\rangle$.

An example can be with $C=2$ and $N=4$. Then `InitializeColor` should apply a Unitary Operation which transform $|0000\rangle$ into $|0100\rangle$ assuming LittleEndian encoding or $|0010\rangle$ assuming BigEndian encoding.